# How to format D3 axis using a unix timestamp with timezone from postgres

Tags: java, javascript, postgresql, d3.js, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm trying to format my x-axis on a D3 line chart, but the values are completely wrong.
The data originates from a Postgres database 'timestamp with timezone' column which I'm converting to json to serve up via D3.

D3 snippet

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.timestamp = new Date(d.timestamp*1000);
    d.close=+d.close;
}
var timeFormat = d3.time.format("%d %b %y %X");
var x = d3.time.scale().range([ 0, width ]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickFormat(timeFormat);
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
        return d.timestamp;
    }));
```

Java conversion to JSON

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from price_data order by timestamp);
...     
String.format("{\"timestamp\":\"%d\",\"close\":\"%f\"}",rs.getTimestamp("timestamp").getTime(),rs.getDouble("price"));
```

Result of axis formatting for timestamp with value 1426014732000
[image: Incorrect axis display format interpretation]

What I don't understand though is that the timeFormat function works fine when stepping through my javascript and calling it via a watch expression in Chrome...
[image]

Comment: Maybe something like: var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickFormat(function(d){return timeFormat(new Date(d));}); ?

Comment: @HuguesStefanski Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately that does not work. The documentation on D3 states that d3.time.format(xxxx) returns an actual function and the data points are already converted to use actual Date objects - I've updated my D3 snippet accordingly to show this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why this is happening I still don't know, but the fix was changing the data transformation to not multiply the timestamp by 1000 as suggested everywhere online.

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  //d.timestamp = new Date(d.timestamp*1000);
  d.close=+d.close;
}
var timeFormat = d3.time.format("%d %b %y %X");
var x = d3.time.scale().range([ 0, width ]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickFormat(timeFormat);
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
        return d.timestamp;
    }));
```

Now the the timestamps are drawn correctly. Perhaps PostgreSql timestamps are already using milliseconds as expected in Javascript. I will investigate and report back for anyone who might be interested in this in future.

Answer (score 0):

Looks as though you're doing most things right, but without the full code it's not really possible to tell. How are you computing the `domain` for the `scale`?  Something like:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data));
```

Regardless, I've put together this [simple example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bjn20zwu/), which may help.

Comment: I'll work up a fiddle once I get time again. The domain is done pretty much like you said yes. I've added the line to the original question.